# Cropping image in ovalShape in Android

Tags: android

I am taking the image from the gallery. my app I have man image, now I need to convert the shape of image which I took from the gallery as oval so that this image is replaced the head part of the man image in my app. I don't know how to crop the the imageview as shape like man face. Do I need to use layer drawables? or layerlist? How to do that?